# Should divs be encapsulated inside wrapper div to prevent them from disappering/repositioning on viewport resize

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties positioning divs on the screen. I want them to be positioned inline, I have specified `display:inline-block` or `float:` or a combination thereof. However whenever I re-size the window the divs disappear or re-position below each other. I read a solution that suggested to encapsulate the divs inside a wrapper div and tried that solution but I stumble upon the same problem since I want the wrapper div to occupy the full height of the screen with no y overflow so if I specify a `height:100%` the child elements re-size whenever the window re-sizes;

```
------------------
header
------------------
div1   div2   div3


------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stick to your design, add this CSS code to your body:-

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:  0px;
}

wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#divOne {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

#divTwo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

#divThree {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

Giving them a fixed but relative width will stop the problem of repositioning of `div`s. Add div1, div2 and div3 inside the wrapper div.

NOTE: The border-box property will take care of the extra margin, border or padding you add.

Comment: Since I want them to be positioned inline, could I use display:inline-block instead?

Comment: While floating a `div`, both `inline-block` and `block` will render similar results.